# Use of unresolved identifier 'NSRunLoop'

Tags: swift, xcode6

Swift complaints that `NSRunLoop` is a unresolved identifier in `main.swift`

```
import Foundation
let runloop = NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop();
runloop.run();
```

Why? Isn't `NSRunLoop` a part of Foundation?

[image]

Comment: Your code works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'Product'->'Clean' will clear the error message. But it will reappear when I tried to run the script in XCode.

The project was created in XCode 6 beta 2.

If I created a new project in XCode 6 beta 3, the script will not cause the same error.